# Hiding the bundle.js until login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react web app of an admin panel built using `webpack`.

I have my `index.html` with a `bundle.js`.

The `bundle.js` is getting loaded when the user enters the first page `login page...`.

For security matters I want to hide the `bundle.js` until the user authenticates! (The bundle includes paths to server side endpoints)

Any ideas of how this should be done?

Comment: You can use the code splitting feature of webpack. More on this here https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/.

Comment: Why do you serve the js file on your login page then?

Comment: @trixn Because the login page also uses assets from the bundle.js....

Comment: @Eduardo Rocha I will look it through